# Displaying a string with variables in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I have little quiz game I've working on and am tracking correct answers.
I have a text object that displays the number of consecutive correct answers. This is the content:

```
content: bind consecutive.toString();
```

What I would like to do is mix that in with some string output like this:

```
content: "{bind consecutive.toString()} in a row!"
```

Unfortunately that gives me an error complaining about the bind keyword.
Creating some intermediary variable is not much better:

```
var consec_disp = bind consecutive;
content: "{consec_disp.toString()} in a row!"
```

Although this compiles it only ever displays "0 in a row!"

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
content: bind "{consecutive.toString()} in a row!"
```

Unless I'm horribly mistaken that should solve your problem.

Comment: Ha! I thought of it but for some reason wrote it off thinking it would never work. Obviously I was wrong because it works like a charm.
Thanks Eric!

Comment: No prob :) Anytime you have questions, post 'em here and I'll get to them since I review all the javafx questions.

Answer (score 0):

Better yet:

```
content: bind "{consecutive} in a row!"
```

{} implies that toString() will be called on the variable.